# How to show variables from Ruby in HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have many variables like:

```
@a = '<b>bla bla</b>'
```

They appear in the browser in the same way. I need code that can translate them into HTML so that they will appear as:

**bla bla**

Comment: With "Translate it to HTML", you mean using a markup language? Do you use ERB, Markdown, ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to print it as HTML

```
@a = '<b>bla bla</b>'.html_safe
```

`html_safe()` will not escape any characters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use html helpers?

http://sraji.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/how-to-display-html-tags-in-rails-helper-methods/

http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/